# Can we fill gmail text field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to execute jquery on address bar, but can't fill the value of gmail text field

My Code is:

```
javascript: $('#email').val("someaddress@gmail.com");
```

But it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use pure Javascript instead:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = "youraddress@gmail.com";
```

Comment: Console Showing Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: Ya.. its working on console but not in address bar..whenever i type on address bar its replace the page and show email id...

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not use jQuery, you would need to use vanilla email for this:

`document.querySelector('#email').value = "youraddress@gmail.com";`

Comment: Console Showing:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: Then there is no input field with the id of email on the page, right click the field you are wanting to populate and select Inspect element, there should be an id that you can target